# general proof of the best Approximation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

**Let $f \in L^2 (0,1)$. Show that for any positive integer n there exists a unique polynomial $p_n$ of degree $\leq$ to $n$ such that $\|f-p\| \geq \|f- p_n\| $ for all polynomials $p$ of degree $\leq$ $n$.**

I think I'll need to consider the orthogonal projection onto the space of polynomials of degree at most n, but I am really stuggling to just start the proof. If someone could guide me through it I will appreciate it.

Comment: What you've suggested is a good way to do it. What is the definition of orthogonal projection, and what facts do you know about it?

Comment: In my text, orthogonal projections are only defined for vectors. Do the same characteristics hold for projections of functions?

Comment: The basic properties of orthogonal projections are satisfied in any Hilbert space, of which $L^2(0,1)$ is an example.

Comment: Ok, so I know now that I can decompose the function into its components. And I know that the inner product of functions is the integral of the product....but i still dont know where to begin this proof.